Generic class constructor passes typechecking but arguably shouldn't
Given:
class Rx<F extends unknown[], T> {
    constructor(
        _dependencies: { [k in keyof F]: Rx<any, F[k]> },
        _calculation: (...args: F) => T,
    ) { }
}

const fortyTwo: Rx<[], number> = new Rx([], () => 42);
const twentySeven: Rx<[], string> = new Rx([], () => "27");

So far so good.
Since twentySeven has type Rx<[], string>, I expect the following line to fail typechecking, but it passes:
const unexpected = new Rx([fortyTwo, twentySeven], (a: number, b: number) => a + b)

Variable unexpected gets assigned type Rx<[number, number], number>. I expected Rx<[number, string], number> and a type error.

What am I doing wrong?
How do I fix it?


Your Rx<F, T> class instance type is just an empty interface, independent of F and T. You could write const x: Rx<[], number> = "abcde" and it will work. I can't believe your actual use case has empty classes with no structural dependency on anything, so this might not be a proper [mre]. See the FAQ and look for "empty classes" and "type parameters which are unused". As soon as I actually add any type-param-dependent structure to your example, as shown here, then you get the errors you expect, more or less.

(see prev comment) So what can we do here? Right now I'd say this is either not a [mre] and you need to [edit] to show something closer to your use case, or you truly are writing empty classes, and the answer is "stop doing that". How would you like to proceed here?

Indeed, adding any structural elements to Rx makes type-checking fail as expected. If you copy your comment into an answer, I'll happily mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Sure, so... does that mean you really were using empty classes? What's the use case? I'm curious because usually people respond "well, of course my actual use case puts stuff in the classes, I just removed it because I thought it wasn't necessary to reproduce my issue", and then we edit to something more indicative of the use case, and then move forward with the actual problem. Here it looks like the actual problem is that the class is empty. So I'm curious what the use case would be for that.

Yes, I was programming type-first: Defining all my types and writing the implementations later. This practice comes from other languages. I'm new to typescript. Today I learned I'll have to adjust my approach slightly when writing TS.

Well you can still write your types first; it's just that your instance type was empty. Indeed you can write everything with declare and do only types and no implementation as shown here. I'll write an answer soon.

TypeScript's type system is largely structural and not nominal. Two types that do not differ in terms of their object shape or structure, are considered not to differ in their type, either.  Your Rx<F, T> class instance type is completely empty.  The shape is the empty object type {}. So therefore all Rx<F, T> instance types are the same type, and just about anything is assignable to it. Unless you are intending for such assignability, you should not have empty classes whose types have nothing to do with your generic type parameters. See the TypeScript FAQ entries for "Why do these empty classes behave strangely?" and "Why is A<string> assignable to A<number> for interface A<T> { }?"?
You should add structure to your class instance type. The easiest thing to do is just give the class properties corresponding to the constructor arguments (I mean, you would do that, right?):
class Rx<F extends unknown[], T> {
  dependencies;
  calculation;
  constructor(
    _dependencies: { [K in keyof F]: Rx<any, F[K]> },
    _calculation: (...args: F) => T,
  ) {
    this.dependencies = _dependencies;
    this.calculation = _calculation;
  }
}

This gives your class a type like
declare class Rx<F extends unknown[], T> {
  dependencies: { [K in keyof F]: Rx<any, F[K]>; };
  calculation: (...args: F) => T;
  constructor(_dependencies: {
    [K in keyof F]: Rx<any, F[K]>;
  }, _calculation: (...args: F) => T);
}

So now an instance of Rx<F, T> has a calcluation property of type (...args: F) => T which should be enough to begin to place restrictions you need:
const fortyTwo: Rx<[], number> = new Rx([], () => 42);
const twentySeven: Rx<[], string> = new Rx([], () => "27");

const unexpected = new Rx(
  [fortyTwo, twentySeven], // error!
  //         ~~~~~~~~~~~
  // Type 'Rx<[], string>' is not assignable to type 'Rx<any, number>'.
  (a: number, b: number) => a + b
)

Playground link to code
